# PHP stmt UPDATE doesn't working for some reason

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I want to UPDATE my news table in the database, but it doesn't working

I already tried without statement, just a simple query, without ?.

Here is the fool code:

```php
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST["submit-Editnews"]) && $_SESSION["uAdmin"] > 0) {
  require 'database.inc.php';

  $nID = $_POST["submit-Editnews"];
  $nTitle = $_POST["editnews-Title"];
  $nCategory = $_POST["editnews-Category"];
  $nText = $_POST["editnews-Text"];
  $nFeatured = $_POST["editnews-Featured"];
  $nFDate = "0000-00-00";
  $nHide = $_POST["editnews-Hide"];
  if ($nFeatured == "1") {
    $nFDate = $_POST["editnews-FeaturedDate"];
  }
  $nFeaturedDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($nFDate));
  $nComments = $_POST["editnews-Comments"];
  if (empty($nTitle) || empty($nText)) {
    header("Location: ../subpages/settings.php?id=".$_SESSION["uID"]."&page=news&error=".$stmt->error);
    exit();
  } else {
    $sql = "UPDATE news SET nTitle=?, nText=?, cID=?, nFeatured=?, nFeaturedDate=?, nEnableComm=?, nHide=? WHERE nID=?";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        header("Location: ../subpages/settings.php?id=".$_SESSION["uID"]."&page=news&error=".$stmt->error);
        exit();
    } else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssiisiii", $nTitle, $nText, $nCategory, $nFeatured, $nFeaturedDate, $nComments, $nHide, $nID);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        header("Location: ../subpages/settings.php?id=".$_SESSION["uID"]."&page=news&error=".$stmt->error);
        exit();
    }
  }
} else {
  header("Location: ../news.php");
  exit();
}
```

It doesn't give any error message. The whole code running through, and does nothing.

Comment: Are you sure, all your conditions are satisfied and `mysqli_stmt_execute()`function got executed?

Comment: I do the same how I did with the in the INSERT news page, and I checked the ```$stmt->execute``` and ```$stmt->error``` but it says it's fine.

Comment: Try to output bind params and see: are they valid? Especially what the value of `$nID`

Comment: Okay, the problem was the ```$nID``` :D I didn't add the id to the button's value. Thanks a lot for the help!